# how to run get the notification based on x,y,z axis values?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application, in that I want to get the notification based on (x,y,z) axis values. But the main problem is how to get the (x,y,z) values when the application is in sleeping mode? So tell me how to get that values in the sleeping mode?
Please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First of, you will need to set the background mode to location, then you will only recieve major location changes.
You can retrieve these location changes withe the standard location manager.

After you checked the x,y position, you have to set a UILocalNotification.

You will need to read this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW11